# MySQL: Select rows as columns and move to next row

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQl tables where I save questions in one and their answers in the another. However I save these answers for each question in a new row of the table.

Ex:
Table name: question

```
id | question
--------------
1  | Blood pressure?
2  | Test date?
```

Table name: answer

```
id | question_id | patient_id | answer
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | 1          | 120/80
2  | 2           | 1          | 2018-01-01
--------------------------------------------
3  | 1           | 1          | 115/81
4  | 2           | 1          | 2018-02-01
--------------------------------------------
5  | 1           | 1          | 121/85
6  | 2           | 1          | 019-05-01
```

My requirement is to list these answers in a columnar structure but to skip to the next row when one set of answers are displayed.

```
Blood pressure? | Test date?
------------------------------
120/80          | 2018-01-01
115/81          | 2018-02-01
121/85          | 2019-05-01
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any way of knowing which test date applies to which blood pressure , it would be unsafe to assume that id is useful..don't you have something like patient id in answers?

Comment: really good question

Comment: @P.Salmon  It does have patient id in answers but that too can repeat.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mysql 8 or above you could generate row numbers based on patient_id and id in answers then self join to get the odd an even answers

```
with cte as
(select a.id,patient_id,a.question_id,q.question,a.answer , 
         row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by a.id) rn
from  answer a
join  question q on q.id = a.question_id
)
select cte.answer,c1.answer
from cte
join cte as c1 on c1.patient_id = cte.patient_id and c1.rn = cte.rn + 1
where cte.rn % 2 <> 0;

+--------+------------+
| answer | answer     |
+--------+------------+
| 120/80 | 2018-01-01 |
| 115/81 | 2018-02-01 |
| 121/85 | 2019-05-01 |
+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```